# How do you get a div class inside a div class inside a div class?

Tags: java, android, parsing, selector, jsoup

My problem is that I need to get a div class inside a div class inside a div class and the are 4 instances of the classes with the same name but different data...
I can currently get the first div class inside the div class but i need to be able to access other elements within it aswell......for example:

```
docTide = Jsoup.connect("http://www.mhpa.co.uk/search-tide-times/").timeout(600000).get();
Elements tideTableRows = docTide.select("div.tide_row.odd");
Element firstDiv = tideTableRows.first();
Element secondDiv = tideTableRows.get(1);
System.out.println("This is the first div: " + firstDiv.text());
System.out.println("This is the second div: " + secondDiv.text());
```

but this is the structure of the webpage where there are 2 repeats and I need to access each of them e.g:

```
 <div class="tide_row odd"> 
  <div class="time">00:57</div>
  <div class="height_m">4.9</div>
  <div class="height_f">16,1</div>
  <div class="range_m">1.9</div>
  <div class="range_f">6,3</div>
  </div>
 <div class="tide_row even">
  <div class="time">07:23</div>
  <div class="height_m">2.9</div>
  <div class="height_f">9,6</div>
  <div class="range_m">2</div>
  <div class="range_f">6,7</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tide_row odd">
  <div class="time">13:46</div>
  <div class="height_m">5.1</div>
  <div class="height_f">16,9</div>
  <div class="range_m">2.2</div>
  <div class="range_f">7,3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tide_row even">
  <div class="time">20:23</div>
  <div class="height_m">2.8</div>
  <div class="height_f">9,2</div>
  <div class="range_m">2.3</div>
  <div class="range_f">7,7</div>
  </div>
```

So basically it has nested classes in separate classes with the same name, how can I construct the correct syntax to return the data from the classes separately?
This is quite hard to explain!

Edit: This is how I managed to extract the information from the nested classes:

```
 docTide = Jsoup.connect("http://www.mhpa.co.uk/search-tide-times/").timeout(600000).get();
                         Elements tideTimeOdd = docTide.select("div.tide_row.odd div:eq(0)");
                         Elements tideTimeEven = docTide.select("div.tide_row.even div:eq(0)");
                         Elements tideHightOdd = docTide.select("div.tide_row.odd div:eq(2)");
                         Elements tideHightEven = docTide.select("div.tide_row.even div:eq(2)");
                            Element firstTideTime = tideTimeOdd.first();
                            Element secondTideTime = tideTimeEven.first();
                            Element thirdTideTime = tideTimeOdd.get(1);
                            Element fourthTideTime = tideTimeEven.get(1);

                            Element firstTideHight = tideHightOdd.first();
                            Element secondTideHight = tideHightEven.first();
                            Element thirdTideHight = tideHightOdd.get(1);
                            Element fourthTideHight = tideHightEven.get(1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would work fine by just doing:

```
 docTide = Jsoup.connect("http://www.mhpa.co.uk/search-tide-times/").timeout(600000).get();
                            Elements tideTableRows = docTide.select("div[class=tide_row odd]");
                            Element firstDiv += tideTableRows.select("div[class=time]");
                            Element secondDiv += tideTableRows.select("div[class=height]");
```

**You should try to access elements by id if you can.** It makes your code a lot simpler and if you have 50 headers in the same container, as an example, this way you don't have to count them all.

**Seperate elements:**

```
 docTide = Jsoup.connect("http://www.mhpa.co.uk/search-tide-times/").timeout(600000).get();
                            Element tideTableRows = docTide.select("div[class=tide_row odd]").first();
                            Element firstDiv1 = tideTableRows.select("div[class=time]");
                            Element secondDiv1 = tideTableRows.select("div[class=height]");
                            tideTableRows2 = docTide.select("div[class=tide_row odd]").second();
                            Element firstDiv2 = tideTableRows.select("div[class=time]");
                            Element secondDiv2 = tideTableRows.select("div[class=height]");
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, As there a 2 "div class tide row odd" and 2 "div class tide row even" with different data in each does this allow me to access the data separately?

Comment: Just tried it and still have the problem that it is accessing the 2 classes different classes (tide row even) or (tide row odd) but called the same and return the values from each of the the classes. Any ideas?

Comment: @J4C3N-14 if you want to add the element you are retrieving to your Elements, then you should do the edit I just made.

Comment: @J4C3N-14 if you want to access and store the div data for the first class and then the second, do the other thing I will post

Comment: hiya, yes I came to this similar conclusion last night and revised my code this morning, now I have seen your answer, i'll edit my question to include my new code and accept your answer as the correct one, thank you.

Comment: @J4C3N-14 thanks, I am sorry you didn't see my answer. You can always edit it with your "neater" code and I will definitly accept it

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
docTide = Jsoup.connect("http://www.mhpa.co.uk/search-tide-times/").timeout(600000).get();
Elements tideTableRows = docTide.select("div.tide_row");
for (Element tideTableRow : tideTableRows){
  if (tideTableRow.hasClass("odd")){
     //do the odd stuff...
  }
  Elements innerDivs = tideTableRows.select("div");

  for (Element innerDiv : innerDivs){
    //do whatever you need
  }
}
```

Note: The code is not tested.

**Update:** I showed you how to access the odd rows only... From there you should be able to get the rest by yourself I hope.

Comment: Is this going to return the values for both of the classes called tide row odd and tide row even, i want to be able to get the data separate.Thanks

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. have now figured how to do it.

Comment: there is a perfectly valid way of appreciating help here. that is upvoting ;)

Comment: ...and have now done so, should of done that before. thanks again.